# Unable to get the FindNext Property of the Range Class using Delete Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a simple macro to search and delete an entire row. Unfortunately I am getting an error on `Set c= .FindNext(c)`

```
Sub DeleteHeaderError()
    With Worksheets(1).Range("a2:a10000")
    Set c = .Find("Create Time", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Select
            Rows(c.Row).DELETE Shift:=xlUp
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't very well use `c` as a range argument to `findnext` when you just deleted it. Try simply:

```
Sub DeleteHeaderError()
    With Worksheets(1).Range("a2:a10000")
    Set c = .Find("Create Time", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Do
            Rows(c.Row).DELETE Shift:=xlUp
            Set c = .Find("Create Time", LookIn:=xlValues)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

By the way, you should never use this:

```
Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
```

If `c` is `Nothing` then attempting to access `c.Address` will cause an error. (I know it's in all the help file examples, but it's still wrong!)

Comment: Yes, this is more concise than what I have below.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast answer. I especially appreciate the warning against 'Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress'